# AWS ECS SDK.Register new container instance (EC2) for ECS Cluster using SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2, sdk, amazon-ecs

I've faced with the problem while using AWS SDK. Currently I am using SDK for golang, but solutions from other languages are welcome too!

I have ECS cluster created via [SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ecs/#CreateClusterInput.)

Now I need to add EC2 containers for this cluster. My problem is that I can't use Amazon ECS Agent to specify cluster name via config:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=your_cluster_name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

or something like that. **I can use only SDK**.

I found method called [RegisterContainerInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ecs/#ECS.RegisterContainerInstance).

But it has note:

> This action is only used by the Amazon ECS agent, and it is not
>   intended for use outside of the agent.

It doesn't look like working solution.

I need to understand how (if it's possible) to create working `ECS cluster`using SDK only.

**UPDATE:** 
My main target is that I need to start specified count of servers from my Docker image.
While I am investigating this task i've found that I need:

- create ECS cluster
- assign to it needed count of ec2 instances.
- create Task with my Docker image.
- run it on cluster manually or as service.

So I:

1. Created new cluster via [CreateCluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ecs/#ECS.CreateCluster) method with name "test-cluster".
2. Created new task via [RegisterTaskDefinition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ecs/#ECS.RegisterTaskDefinition)
3. Created new EC2 instance with ecsInstanceRole role with ecs-optimized AMI type, that is correct for my region.
   And there place where problems had started.

Actual result: All new ec2 instances had attached to "default" cluster (AWS created it and attach instance to it).
If I am using ECS agent I can specify cluster name by using ECS_CLUSTER config env. But I am developing tool that use only SDK (without any ability of using ECS agent).
With RegisterTaskDefinition I haven't any possibility to specify cluster, so my question, how I can assign new EC2 instance exactly to specified cluster?

When I had tried to just start my task via [RunTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ecs/#ECS.RunTask) method (with hoping that AWS somehow create instances for me or something like that) I receive an error:

```
InvalidParameterException: No Container Instances were found in your cluster.
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually can't sort out which question you are asking. Do you need to add containers to the cluster, or add instances to the cluster? Those are very different.

#### Add instances to the cluster

This is not done with the ECS API, it is done with the EC2 API by creating EC2 instances with the correct ecsInstanceRole. See the [Launching an Amazon ECS Container Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html) documentation for more information.

#### Add containers to the cluster

This is done be defining a task definition, then running those tasks manually or as services. See the [Amazon ECS Task Definitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html) for more information.

Comment: thank you for your helping, I've updated question. Could you please revise it again?